# My recursive function is not returning anything, why?

Tags: recursion, scheme

So I'm very new to scheme, first day programming in it. I'm trying to make a recursive function that basically takes two arguements `numlist, num` numlist is a list of numbers, and num is a single number. The function takes the list, goes through each element and compares it to num, if the number is greater then num it replaces it in the list with a 1, otherwise it replaces it with a 0.

Ex: arguments( (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) , 5) transforms the list to (0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)

But for some reason my function is not returning anything, it doesn't print anything to my screen, why?

```
(define (greater-nums-in-list numlist num)
    (cond
    [(null? numlist) ()]
    [(> (car numlist) num) (append 1 (greater-nums-in-list((cdr numlist) num))]
    [else (append 0 (greater-nums-in-list((cdr numlist) num)))]
    )
)
```

Any help would be appreciated, this is just personal studying code so I'm in no rush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "nothing" that it prints to screen is because of the base-condition at the bottom of the recursion:

```
[(null? numlist) ()]
```

This means that when you've done iterating the list, you return `()` - that's not an empty-list - that applying "nothing", an empty list is `'()`.

There were a couple of brackets-bugs and you cannot append `1` or `0` to a list - you need to wrap them in a list first:

```
(define (greater-nums-in-list numlist num)
  (cond
    [(null? numlist) '()]
    [(> (car numlist) num) (append '(1) (greater-nums-in-list (cdr numlist) num))]
    [else (append '(0) (greater-nums-in-list (cdr numlist) num))]
    )
  )
```

**Usage**

```
>  (greater-nums-in-list '(1 2 3 4) 2)
'(0 0 1 1)
> (greater-nums-in-list '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) 5)
'(0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1)
>
```

Comment: Ok it does work, my only qualm with with your answer is that with every other language it would return fine, because what happens is it gets all the 0's and 1's and then appends them at the end of the recursion so if you had (1,2,3) and 1 it would go 0 append (2,3) -> 0 append 1 append (3) -> 0 append 1 append 1 append () -> (0, 1, 1)
You know? Like in F# this would work perfectly fine, but whatever. Your solution works great, I just really don't understand why mine doesn't

Comment: @ManPerson The updated solution is a fix of your code, please check it out. I was mistaken in my earlier comment...